# onModuleLoad() threw an exception

Tags: gwt

I am trying to insert textbox widget into HTML page of my website, but I am getting the following exception. I am using gwt with Eclipse Luna 4.4.

```
    onModuleLoad() threw an exception
    Exception while loading module com.student.appamsoft.client.AppamSoftPvtLtd. See Development Mode for details.
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:411) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.student.appamsoft.client.AppamSoftPvtLtd.onModuleLoad(AppamSoftPvtLtd.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:411)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**My onModuleLoad() method contents are :**

```
 TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox(); 
  TextBox textBox2 = new TextBox();

  //add text to text box
  textBox2.setText("Hello World!");

  //set textbox as readonly
  textBox2.setReadOnly(true);

  // Add text boxes to the root panel.
  VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
  panel.setSpacing(10);
  panel.add(textBox1);
  panel.add(textBox2);

  RootPanel.get("tb5").add(panel);
```

Comment: In cases of using something like RootPanel.get("id") and geting a NPE, there is nothing in the DOM-Tree with an id you are looking for. Check, if your host page contains a div, td or something else with the id of "tb5".

Comment: Yes there is a div tag which contains id ="tb5" in my html page.

Comment: sir what could be the other cause of this exception?

Comment: "AppamSoftPvtLtd.java:49" Is line 49 RootPanel.get("tb5").add(panel); ? Maybe try a clean, refresh, rebuild project?

Comment: sir, I got it , I am getting textbox on my html page after clean the project.

Comment: Thanks and thanks once again.

Comment: @Ovi and Praveen: If you've reached a solution, please post it as an answer or delete the question if the solution was a simple mistake/fix/oversight and might not be helpful to others. Because as it is, this question is "unanswered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error removed by after **cleaning and refereshing** my project in eclipse. And  this suggestion came from @Ovi Faur.
This Error may be helpful for those people who are beginners like me in GWT.